# How can I add a custom button to Add and Edit posts / pages?

Tags: wordpress

What function / hook do I need to use in order to insert a button here, on the Add and Edit post pages?

Thank you very much!

[image: Add button here]

Comment: Read the documentation here http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference and here http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference

Answer (score 1):

the hook you are looking for is media_buttons_context. You could do something like the following:

```
add_action('media_buttons_context',  'add_my_custom_button');

function add_my_custom_button($context) {

  //path to my icon
  $img = 'penguin.png';

  //our popup's title
  $title = 'An Inline Popup!';

  //append the icon
  $context .= "<a title='{$title}' href='#'>
      <img src='{$img}' /></a>";

  return $context;
}
```

Source [Here!](http://themergency.com/adding-custom-buttons-to-the-wordpress-content-editor-part-1/)